# Convert perl to shell or bash for communication over gpio

Tags: bash, perl

I new to perl but understand C and C++ and . I want to converting the perl script under the following url to shell or bash:
https://code.google.com/p/busware/source/browse/trunk/SD0/Firmware_VZ/vzfeeder/vzfeeder.pl

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Time::HiRes qw/ gettimeofday /;;
use POE;
use POE::Wheel::ReadWrite;
use POE::Wheel::ReadLine;
use POE::Component::Client::HTTP;
use POE::Component::DBIAgent;
use Symbol qw(gensym);
use Device::SerialPort;
use POE::Filter::Line;
use HTTP::Request;
use Data::Dumper;
use DateTime;

sub DB_NAME () { "volkszaehler" }
sub DB_USER () { "vz" }
sub DB_PASS () { "demo" }

use Log::Log4perl qw/:easy/;
Log::Log4perl->easy_init( {
                           level  => $INFO,
                           layout => '[%d] %p %c - %m%n',
                          } );

INFO('starting logger process');

POE::Session->create(
  inline_states => {
    _start      => \&setup_device,
    open_serial => \&open_serial,
    program_serial => \&program_serial,
    got_serial  => \&got_serial,
    got_error   => \&handle_errors,
    cmd_V       => \&got_version,
    cmd_L       => \&got_portbits,
    queue_cmd   => \&queue_cmd,

    mod_reset   => \&mod_reset,
    mod_bl      => \&mod_bl,

    query_all_channels_done => \&handle_query_all_channels_response,
    finish_query_all_channels => \&finish_query_all_channels,
  },
)->option( trace => 1 );

POE::Kernel->run();
exit 0;

sub setup_device {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $session) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION];

  POE::Component::Client::HTTP->spawn(
                                      Alias     => 'ua',
                                      Timeout   => 10,
                                     );

  INFO('opening database link');
  my $dbi = $heap->{dbi_helper} = POE::Component::DBIAgent->new(
    DSN     => ['dbi:mysql:dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS],
    Count   => 3,
    Queries => {
      query_all_channels  => 'select * from entities',
      insert_tickdata     => 'insert into data (timestamp,channel_id,value) values (?, ?, ?)',
#      update => "update test set value = ? where name = ?",
#      delete => "delete from test where name = ?",
    },
  );

  $heap->{CHANNELS} = [];
  $dbi->query(query_all_channels => $session->ID => 'query_all_channels_done');

  $kernel->yield( 'open_serial' );
}

# open serial Port
sub open_serial {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $session, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION, ARG0];

  INFO('opening serial port');

  qx^if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio27; then echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi^;
  qx^echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction^;
  qx^echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value^;
  qx^if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio17; then echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi^;
  qx^echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction^;
  qx^echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value^;
  qx^echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value^;

  # Open a serial port, and tie it to a file handle for POE.
  my $handle = gensym();
  my $port = tie(*$handle, "Device::SerialPort", "/dev/ttyAMA0");
  die "can't open port: $!" unless $port;

  $port->datatype('raw');
  $port->reset_error();
  $port->baudrate(38400);
  $port->databits(8);
  $port->parity('none');
  $port->stopbits(1);
  $port->handshake('none');

  $port->write_settings();

  $port->lookclear();

  # Start interacting with the GPS.
  $heap->{port}       = $port;
  $heap->{port_wheel} = POE::Wheel::ReadWrite->new(
    Handle => $handle,
    Filter => POE::Filter::Line->new(
      InputLiteral  => "\x0D\x0A",    # Received line endings.
      OutputLiteral => "\x0D",        # Sent line endings.
    ),
    InputEvent => "got_serial",
    ErrorEvent => "got_error",
  );

  $kernel->delay_add( queue_cmd => 2 => 'v' ); 
  $kernel->delay( program_serial => 5 ); 
}

# programming via serial Port
sub program_serial {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $session, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION, ARG0];

  INFO('flashing module @ serial port');

  delete $heap->{port_wheel};
  untie( $heap->{port} ) if $heap->{port};
  delete ( $heap->{port} );

  qx^if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio17; then echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi^;
  qx^echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction^;
  qx^echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value^;
  qx^if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio27; then echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi^;
  qx^echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction^;
  qx^echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value^;
  qx^echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value^;
  qx^sleep 1^;
  qx^echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value^;
  qx^avrdude -p atmega1284p -P /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 38400 -c avr109 -U flash:w:main.hex^;

  $kernel->yield( 'open_serial' );
}


# Port data (lines, separated by CRLF) are displayed on the console.
sub got_serial {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $session, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION, ARG0];
  INFO( 'got_serial: ' . $data );
  my @v = split( /\s+/, $data );

  # Channel ticks?
  if ($v[0] =~ /^([ABCD])$/) {
    my $ch = $1;
    INFO( 'Tick @ ' . $ch );
    my ($seconds, $microseconds) = gettimeofday;
    my $sec = sprintf( '%d%03d', $seconds, $microseconds/1000 );

    $heap->{dbi_helper}->query( insert_tickdata => $session->ID => undef => ($sec, ord($ch)-64, 1));

    return;
  } 

  my $cmd = sprintf 'cmd_%s', shift @v;
  $kernel->yield( $cmd => [@v] );
}

# Error on the serial port.  Shut down.
sub handle_errors {
  my $heap = $_[HEAP];
  ERROR( 'received error!' );
  delete $heap->{port_wheel};
}

sub got_version {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];
  INFO( 'VERSION: ' . $data->[0] );
  $heap->{VERSION} = $data->[0];

  $kernel->delay( 'program_serial' );
}

sub got_portbits {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];
  INFO( 'Portbits: ' . $data->[0] );
  $heap->{PORTBITS} = $data->[0];
}

sub queue_cmd {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];
  $heap->{port_wheel}->put( $data );
}

#
# DATABASE work
#

sub handle_query_all_channels_response {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];

  if (ref($data) eq 'ARRAY') {
    push $heap->{CHANNELS}, $data;
  } elsif ($data eq 'EOF') {
    $kernel->yield( finish_query_all_channels => $heap->{CHANNELS} );
  }

}

sub finish_query_all_channels {
  my ($kernel, $heap, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, ARG0];
  INFO( Dumper($heap->{CHANNELS}));
}
```

Here is a part of the perl script as shell/bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh

function setup_device() {{

}
function open_Serial(){
    echo "opening serial port; Resetting\\Booting the SD0"

    if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio27; then echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi
    echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction
    echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value
    if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio17; then echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi
    echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
    echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
    echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
    minicom -b 38400 -o -D /dev/ttyAMA0
}

function program_Serial(){
    echo "flashing module @ serial port"
    echo calling co-processor bootloader ...

    if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio17; then echo 17 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi
    echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/direction
    echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
    if test ! -d /sys/class/gpio/gpio27; then echo 27 > /sys/class/gpio/export; fi
    echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/direction
    echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value
    echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio17/value
    sleep 1
    echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio27/value

    avrdude -p atmega1284p -P /dev/ttyAMA0 -b 38400 -c avr109 -U flash:w:SD0.hex
}
```

What does for Example

```
my ($kernel, $heap, $session, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION, ARG0];
```

mean? I gues parameter for the function(?) but how to convert ARG?
Or what is the following code doing?

```
my $handle = gensym();
```

Is there a Tool which is converting a perl script to shell? Or a (good Doc) which can help to translate?

Comment: All you appear to have done is remove `qx` from around the parts of the script that use it, which shouldn't be written that way in the first place. This is a substantial amount of work, and I don't know what help you expect here. There is nothing that will convert Perl to any other language, and cannot be in general because of its intertwined and simultaneous compilation and execution capability. What is the problem with running the Perl program as it is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your Perl program is built around [POE (the *Perl Object Environment*)](http://poe.perl.org/) which is an event loop mechanism that allows multiple independent tasks to be executed in parallel in response to events, messages, or elapsed time. It is a comprehensive set of modules that has a counterpart in other languages, but isn't directly replicated anywhere

> What does for Example
>
> ```
> my ($kernel, $heap, $session, $data) = @_[KERNEL, HEAP, SESSION, ARG0];
> ```
>
> mean? I gues parameter for the function(?) but how to convert ARG?

That is part of the `POE` calling mechanism. Parameters are passed to Perl subroutines in the `@_` array, and `POE` has a convention that the same parameters are always passed in the same order to its member subroutines. The values `KERNEL`, `HEAP` etc. are simply numeric constants that are used to label indices into the parameter list. For instance `SESSION`, `KERNEL` and `HEAP` are 1, 2, and 3 respectively. `ARG0` is 10, so it picks the eleventh element of `@_`. Other values are defined

> Or what is the following code doing?
>
> ```
> my $handle = gensym();
> ```

That is a very esoteric corner of Perl. `gensym` is provided by the [`Symbol` module](https://metacpan.org/pod/Symbol), and in this case it is a way of creating a file handle without giving it a specific identifier

> Is there a Tool which is converting a perl script to shell? Or a (good Doc) which can help to translate?

There is nothing that will convert a general Perl program to any other language because, as I intimated in my comment above, Perl has a unique way of intertwining compilation and execution phases that no other language shares. There may be something around that will convert very basic Perl, but I haven't come across it, and anyway your code doesn't qualify as *basic*

The best documentation for Perl itself is in [`perldoc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/), and [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/) will help you with the documentation for individual modules, in addition to the website for POE which I linked above